# Regular Expression in Varnish? What does this regex matches?

Tags: regex, varnish

I see in my log a purge request going to varnish of the form
`req.url ~ "^(.*)(?<!\\d{1})534328(?!\\d{1})"`. I am not sure what the regex matches exactly. I know varnish uses POSIX regular expressions. I am trying to generate sample matches for the regex `^(.*)(?<!\\d{1})534328(?!\\d{1})` but could not fine a tool to help me.

Edit: Sorry, I made a mistake `The regular expression engine is now PCRE instead of POSIX regular expressions.` according to the [changelog here.](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/changelog_2.0.6-2.1.0)

Comment: If Varnish does use POSIX regexes, then this regex won't work because lookaround assertions aren't supported by POSIX regexes.

Comment: [Varnish uses PCRE](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vcl.html#regular-expressions).

Comment: Sorry I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

It matches `534328` that is neither preceded nor followed by a digit.

```
^            # line beginning
(.*)         # any character repeated any number of times, including 0
(?<!\d{1})   # negative look-behind assertion: single digit
534328       # literal 534328       
(?!\d{1})    # negative look-ahead assertion: single digit
```

---

```
  "whatever 534328"      ←  match
  "wharrgarbl 1534328"   ←  no match
  "any chars  5343289"   ←  no match
  "hello world a534328b" ←  match
```

- [Lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: No colon required but will it match 534328 at the end of the line?

Comment: Huh? These are just examples in a table. Okay, I'll reformat it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there am online tool, or a C/c++/ or php functions I can test with?

Comment: Not sure which online tool is best, but in PHP the [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function and its friends use PCRE.

Comment: I haven't tried the PHP version but some of the other versions work wonderfully here: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/php/index.html

Comment: @PavelAnossov The pattern in the varnish log contains 2 backslashes `(?<!\\d{1})` not as you noted `(?<!\d{1})`. this changes the meaning of the regex? Am I correct?